# Select multiple objects with the same name

Tags: vba, image, excel

So I have a sheet with some pictures. All of these are just a copy paste of the original picture so they all have the same name "Flower".

I want to select all of them and flip them. But it will only select the original, how do I get past this? I tried incorporating a loop as well, without luck.

```
Sub Test()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Flower")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Flip msoFlipHorizontal
End Sub
```

I know that I could simply rename them to Flower1, Flower2 etc. but the plan is to use this for a lot of pictures, so it would take to long to change manually. If it could all be done with a loop, that would be fine, but then I would still have the same problem as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop thru the collection `Shapes` looking for the shapes with the given name. Try this.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Pic As Shape
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Pic.Name = "Flower" Then Pic.Flip msoFlipHorizontal
    Next Pic
End Sub
```

In addition, you can code this without selecting it. Faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two objects in VBA that could be useful - the shape collection named `Shapes` and the `Shape` itself. Thus, you can loop through the collection like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim shShape         As Shape
    Dim shCollection    As Shapes

    Set shCollection = ActiveSheet.Shapes

    For Each shShape In shCollection
        shShape.Flip msoFlipHorizontal
    Next shShape

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I'm curious about what is the advantage of setting an object `shCollection` first instead of using it directly?

Comment: @newacc2240 - in this case specific case - no advantage. But if you have to do it twice and you are browsing around the worksheets, then `ActiveSheet.Shape` is a bit unreliable.

Comment: Got it. However I prefer setting a variable ws first, then call it by `ws.Shapes` if it is needed to browsing several worksheets. Thank you :)

Comment: @newacc2240 - it is your choice.